# Magento 2: How can I relate/link custom module data to products like Up Sell or Cross Sell?

Tags: magento2, module, product-relations

I have created modules to store complex information like Dangerous Good Informations (UN-No, Proper Shipping Name, Class, Packing Group etc) or **Customs Numbers** (Taric Codes).

Now, I want to **relate/link** these pieces of information to my products.
For that, I would like to use the same **method/way** like it is used to linking Up-Sell or Cross Sell products.
 Please help.